# How to optimize the insert query time using hiberate?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, wildfly-10

I have about 1.4 million records of data but it is taking more than 3hr to insert them. I cannot seems to find the problem to it.

I read up and change from identity to sequence. It only improved by a little but it still take quite a long time to finish insert.

I am using:

- Hibernate 5
- Spring 4
- mssql 2014
- Wildfly 10

applicationContext-hibernate.xml

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice">
        <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*_TransNew" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" />
            <tx:method name="*_NoTrans" propagation="NEVER" />

            <tx:method name="create*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            <tx:method name="update*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            <tx:method name="delete*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            <tx:method name="add*" propagation="REQUIRED" />

            <tx:method name="generate*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            <tx:method name="get*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
            <tx:method name="is*" propagation="REQUIRED" />

            <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
            <tx:method name="*" read-only="true" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>


    <!-- ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution of 
        an operation defined by the following -->
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="demoServiceOperations"
            expression="execution(* com.test.*.*.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="demoServiceOperations" />
    </aop:config>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>


            </props>
        </property>         
    </bean>
```

Umts.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Nov 22, 2016 11:36:21 AM by Hibernate Tools 5.2.0.Beta1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.test.domain.Umts" table="TBLDM_UMTS" schema="dbo" catalog="DEMO" optimistic-lock="version" dynamic-update="true">
        <id name="umtsId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="UMTS_ID" />
            <generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator">
                <param name="optimizer">pooled-lo</param>
                <param name="increment_size">1</param>
                <param name="sequence_name">UMTS_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="cid" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="CI" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="channelNo" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="UARFCN" />
        </property>
        <property name="signalStrength" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="EC_IO" precision="53" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="sc" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="SC" />
        </property>
        <property name="latitude" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="LATITUDE" precision="53" scale="0" />
        </property>
        <property name="longitude" type="java.lang.Double">
            <column name="LONGITUDE" precision="53" scale="0" />
        </property>
         <property name="mcc" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="MCC" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="mnc" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="MNC" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="recvDate" type="date">
            <column name="RECV_DATE" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="recvTime" type="time">
            <column name="RECV_TIME" length="16" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Service class:

```
public void process(List<Umts> umtsList)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < umtsList.size(); i = i + PropertiesUtil.MAX_COMMIT_COUNT)
        {
            int min = i;
            int max = i + PropertiesUtil.MAX_COMMIT_COUNT;

            if (max > umtsList.size())
            {
                max = umtsList.size();
            }

            createUmts_TransNew(umtsList.subList(min, max));
        }
}
    @Override
        public void createUmts_TransNew(Collection list) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            umtsDAO.saveAll(list);  
        }
```

DAO class:

```
@Transactional
    public void saveAll(Collection collection)
    {
        log.debug("** save all");
        try
        {
            if (collection != null && collection.size() > 0)
            {
                for (Object obj : collection)
                {
                    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(obj);                   
                }
            }
        }
        catch (RuntimeException re)
        {
            log.error("** save all failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

** Edited
Does connection pool plays a part here? Meaning does connection pool helps with the performance? Do i need to add the jar file to the wildfly 10 or to application itself?

Comment: why do it in Java? Can you use Batch Insert?

Comment: @ScaryWombat isn't what I done a batch insert?

Comment: see http://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/

Comment: Also looks like `createUmts_TransNew(umtsList.subList(min, max));` is inside your `for` loop

Comment: @ScaryWombat i think that is  actually what i am doing unless my transnew propagration is not working?

Comment: @ScaryWombat my transaction advice in fact do have a problem which i have fixed it. but having said so. The time need to commit is still quite long.

Comment: Can't you write a database procedure to insert these values instead of using Java?

Comment: @Leozeo i would say this is because of the flow on how it was done. I have an application which allow user to update files. I need to preprocess first before i can save to db.

Comment: You can also try by setting show_sql to false because writing 1.4 millions sqls to console/file also takes time. It will also improve the performance.

Comment: @Leozeo oh ok. I will try. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off, try increasing the `pooled-lo` value. Since you set it to 1, there is no optimisation/pooling going on - since every ID that needs to be fetched needs a call to the DB to get the actual value. If you have a bigger increment size, hibernate will pre-fetch/reserve a block of ID's to use for new entities, without a per-entity round-trip.

Not sure how the code you posted is executed, but I'm assuming you're inserting them sequentially in a single thread. You can:

- Use a thread-pool in which each thread takes a number of items from the list/queue to insert.
- The items inserted in a single transaction by one thread has ideally same size as the configured hibernate batch size to again, minimize roundtrips.
- Ensure the number of threads in the pool is in par with the connection pool size, so you don't end up blocking the worker threads when waiting for a connection.
- Ensure connection pool size is reasonable for the load your server can take and use a good connection pool (eg. [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)). Here is an interesting [writeup on connection pool size.](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing)

Comment: should the incremental size follow the cache value in db?

Comment: The cache value on the MSSQL sequence determines the amount of sequence values are kept in memory and only writes to it's system tables every X usages. MSSQL will still increment the sequence by 1 when requested by hibernate, regardless of the cache property of the sequence.

So no, it shouldn't be the same as it's transparant to hibernate how the internal sequence ins handled on the DB - it only sees the increments by 1, when used.

Comment: i am still lost. Even after changing the value, the performance is still the same. Also do I need to add HikariCP as a lib in Wildfly 10 or to my application itself ?

Comment: There is no easy way to use HikariCP as container-managed datasource and if possible, would only bring additional overhead.

Have you tried the other recommendations (using more that one thread to insert data)? Changing the pool isn't needed if you're using multiple threads feeding data in and continuously keeping all connections in use.

Comment: i am actually using c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar for my connection pool (see updated applicationContext-hibernate.xml). But there isn't any change in performance as well.

Comment: And you are using **multiple threads** that feed data into the database at the same time?

Comment: @frederickh From what i read. [https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool?_sscc=t] numHelperThreads Must be set in c3p0.properties, C3P0 default: 3.
the default was set to 3? So I think that is a Yes?

Comment: This is the number of connections C3P0 keeps in his pool, not the number of threads are used. Take a look at `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` (plenty examples out there on how to use it). Easiest test to see if it helps would be: Instead of going over the `List<Umts> umtsList` sequentially, you can split it up into eg. 5 parts. Create an implementation of a `Runnable`, which accepts one part of the lists and starts doing the logic that was in your `saveAll(..)` method. Finally, pass the runnables to the `pooledExecutor.run` to have each runnable instert 1/5th of the list...